# How to separate different levels of y-value on scatter plot?

Tags: powerbi, bar-chart

Lets say I have the following data frame called "event". (plz run the code as "R script" in Power BI to reproduce the table)

```r
    event <- data.frame(id= rep(1,10),
                         domian= c("ae","ae","ae","ae",
                                   "cm","cm","cm","cm",
                                   "ex","ex"),
                        param = c("stress", "stress", "insomnia",
                                  "fatigue", "drug1","drug1", 
                                  "drug2", "drug3","exposure","exposure"),
                        severity = c(2,3,4,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                        day = c(14,14,24,18,14,14,24,33,
                                1,44),
                        start= c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,NA,NA),
                        end  = c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,NA,NA))
```

Initially I had two columns of "**start_day**" and "**end_day**" for each parameter. For the purpose of producing the graph I need, I decided to combine those two columns in one column named "**day**" and also added two new columns as "**start**" and "**end**" to reference if  "day" value comes from "start_day"  or from "end_day" column.

My end goal is to create a graph such that the start and end date for each "param" are shown and connected through a line. Somehow I want to create a similar [graph](https://www.lexjansen.com/phuse/2017/dv/DV05.pdf) as shown bellow.

[image]

It seems I should use **scatter plot** for this purpose, such that y-axis is "param" and x-axis is "day". Using scatter plot creates certain issues, first it sums over the values (for instance the day for drug1 is shown as 30 as a result of summing over 14+16), second problem is that scatter plot omits some data points (for instance "stress"), and finally I intend to show different levels of "param" (stress, insomnia, fatigue, drug1, etc) separately on y-axis.

[image]

Since scatter plot is not producing what I am looking for, I used stacked bar plot just to show what the desired graph would look like.

[image]

In scatter plot, I have each parameter shown separately as I wish it to be shown. But the issue with bar chart is that the shown values are not correct (for instance for stress, the "start_day" and "end_day" are aggregated 14+16=30).

Is Power BI capable of producing the type of graph I am looking for?  Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI can be used to create virtually any chart type you want if you're prepared to use Deneb or Charticulator. Take a look here for various charts you could create.

https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/

https://deneb-viz.github.io/